# Add a label with the special char +

Tags: google-maps, label, marker

I am drawing custom markers on a map and adding labels based on how many people are at that particular address. If there are more than 5 I want to write the label 5+ instead of writing out 23 for example. 1 - 4 work just fine, but I cannot seem to pass the + in a manner that it will display. I do not want to use a static image/marker with the number if I can help it. Anyone done this before?

I have tried this:

```
var res_label = '5+' 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latLng,
map: map,
icon: img,
label: encodeURIComponent(res_label),
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

The pin drops but is blank. I tried wrapping the marker var and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In  a URL a `+` will be used as space, you must encode it: `%2B`

You should use encodeURIComponent() to encode the entire string(there may be more chars which must be encoded)

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.firstChild.data = encodeURIComponent(document.body.firstChild.data);}
```

```html
^1234567890ß´`?=)(/&%$§"!+*~ÄÖLK_:;-.,Q>%
```

### sample-implementation:

```js
function initialize() {
  var goo = google.maps,
    map = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      }
    }),
    //note:the dynamic chart-icons are deprecated and may be disabled som day
    url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?' +
    'chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=',
    marker = new goo
    .Marker({
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter(),
      icon: url +
        encodeURIComponent('bb|text|FFFFFF|000000')
    }),
    btn = document.createElement('input');
  btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  btn.setAttribute('value', 'push me!');
  map.controls[goo.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btn);
  goo.event.addDomListener(btn, 'click', function() {
    var txt;
    if (txt = prompt('type a string', 'text')) {
      marker
        .setIcon(url + encodeURIComponent('bb|' + txt + '|FFFFFF|000000'))
    }
  })
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
input {
  background: tomato;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle I tried your suggestion and put the code above. Perhaps I need to encode it later on? Encoding the whole marker var failed to make the pins drop at all.

Comment: markers doesn't have a `label`-property, I'm not sure what you expect when you add this property.  I've added an working example above

Comment: Using the code I supplied I do get a marker with a label as long as I do not add a special character such as the +

Comment: You may say what you want, when you haven't modified the `google.maps.Marker`-prototype the label-property simply will do nothing. When you see (different) labels you probably have used different icons(with labels), it's onclear what `img` is

Comment: Thanks for your help.without pasting all the code I extended the Marker which I added the label to. I ended up inserting the + later on in my code where it wasn't being stripped.